# How does the "builtin server" work with a Flask web application?

Tags: python, flask, webserver, wsgi

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

> ```
> $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
> $ python -m flask run
>  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
> ```
>
> This launches **a very simple builtin server**, which is good enough for
>   testing but probably not what you want to use in production.

How does the "very simple builtin server" work  with a Flask web application?

- Does the "very simple builtin server" also use WSGI to invoke and communicate with a Flask web application?
- Do the "very simple builtin server" and a Flask web application run in the same or different processes?

If I am correct, an external web server (Apache or Nginx) needs to use WSGI to invoke and communicate a Flask web application, and they run in the same process.

Comment: Flask is not a server, so I'm not sure what you mean by the second bullet point? Without a server, the flask app is just a bunch of code listening and responding to nothing

Comment: If I am correct, an external web server (Apache or Nginx) needs to use WSGI to invoke and communicate a Flask web application, and they run in the same process.

Comment: One typical setup would be Nginx as a load balancer and reverse proxy, and gunicorn acting as the server. The development server uses WSGI, yes, but its explicitly documented to not be used in production. You can serve your application with just gunicorn and not bother with Nginx. I'm less familiar with Apache

Answer (score 3):

It uses the [werkzeug simple WSGI server](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/serving/?highlight=run_simple#werkzeug.serving.run_simple).

It's a single process, single thread server so if I understand your second question correctly it does not use multiple processes. The app is being served by the same python process that is handling the Flask application.